# Grid pattern parallel to borders

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

Attempting to reproduce this picture from an old book (sorry for the resolution)

[image]

I used `tikz`'s `patterns` library to generate the grid, which provides an honorable result.

[image]

However, with the default grid patterns, it doesn't seem to be possible to have a grid parallel to the borders of the path, as in this case obtained using a `foreach`-based grid.

[image]

While this solution works fine, it requires potential fine tuning. 
So, is there a way to define grid patterns for 4 sided paths with parallel borders (of course, this could make no sense for some other shapes) where the grid is parallel to the borders

Here is the code used to generate the pictures

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]

    \draw[pattern={Hatch[distance=5pt]}] (0,0) -- (1,0) to[out=120,in=-95] (1,4) -- (0,4) to[out=-95,in=120] (0,0);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
        \coordinate (sw) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (se) at (1,0);
        \coordinate (nw) at (0,4);
        \coordinate (ne) at (1,4);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\gridstep}{5}
        \path[clip,preaction={draw=black}] (sw) -- (se) to[out=120,in=-95] (ne) -- (nw) to[out=-95,in=120] (sw);
        \draw 
        foreach \xpos in {1,...,10}{($(sw)+(\xpos*\gridstep pt,0)$) to[out=120,in=-95] ($(nw)+(\xpos*\gridstep pt,0)$)}
        foreach \ypos in {1,...,30}{($(-5,0)+(0,\ypos*\gridstep pt)$) -- ($(10,0)+(0,\ypos*\gridstep pt)$)}
        ;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution, from my point of view.

Comment: Related but not exactly the same: [Flexure of a Grid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528089/73317). The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528160/73317) from there does seem to apply here, though.

Comment: @frougon, that is a very interesting thread ! I will check it tomorrow. The answer based on postactions is very clever.

Comment: Yes, that was Grand Wizard Symbol 1, IIRC. :-)

Comment: @frougon There are some wizards in here indeed ! Sometimes, I have the feeling that even though I am using `tikz` close to every day, there is still a incredible amount of information I lack about it. Or my brain is just too slow, who knows

Comment: The PGF & Ti*k*Z ecosystem is extremely powerful. This comes with a price: the need to learn and remain humble...