# How to use \pgftransformnonlinear with tikz axis environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following is a MWE I made to test the use of `\pgftransformnonlinear` on a pgfplot (via Ti*k*Z's `axis` environment). It uses the following map: [image].
(based on the answer here: [Nonlinear transformation of tikzpicture according to a function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426701/nonlinear-transformation-of-tikzpicture-according-to-a-function))

In principal this works ok, but it doesn't really use the coordinates of the `axis` environment itself. Foe example, one can clearly see that the transformation isn't symmetric across the y axis as one would expect. I think this is because `\pgftransformnonlinear` works in a completely different coordiante system than that of the `axis` environment.

So my question is as follows: is there a way to apply non-linear transformations such that they use the coordinates of the internal `axis` environment?

Code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/vector plane/.style={
    },
}
\makeatletter
\def\mytransformation{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\pgf@x}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{0.001*\pgf@x*\pgf@x+\pgf@y}
    \setlength{\pgf@x}{\myX pt}
    \setlength{\pgf@y}{\myY pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \pgftransformnonlinear{\mytransformation}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=10cm, height=10cm,
                axis x line=middle,
                axis y line=middle,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                every axis x label/.style={
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=west,
                },
                every axis y label/.style={
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=south,
                },
                axis line style={stealth-stealth, thick},
                label style={font=\large},
                tick label style={font=\large},
                xticklabels={,,},
                yticklabels={,,},
                samples=100,
                xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                grid=both,
                major grid style={black!5},
                minor grid style={black!5},
                ]
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: The figure generated by the above code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transformation seems to based on an axis origin at (0,0), which may be different than pgf origin (here at bottom left).

One solution would be to place the axis at (0,0) of the pgf (which is also the default behavior), but change the anchor of the axis to origin. Origin is a special anchor for the axis. See pgfplots manual for other anchor options.

```
\begin{axis}[
    at = {(0,0)},
    anchor = {origin},
```

You can, of course omitt the `at = {(0,0)}`, as it default position.

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/vector plane/.style={
    },
}
\makeatletter
\def\mytransformation{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\pgf@x}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{0.001*\pgf@x*\pgf@x+\pgf@y}
    \setlength{\pgf@x}{\myX pt}
    \setlength{\pgf@y}{\myY pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \pgftransformnonlinear{\mytransformation}
            \begin{axis}[
                at = {(0,0)},
                anchor = {origin},
                width=10cm, height=10cm,
                axis x line=middle,
                axis y line=middle,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                every axis x label/.style={
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=west,
                },
                every axis y label/.style={
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=south,
                },
                axis line style={stealth-stealth, thick},
                label style={font=\large},
                tick label style={font=\large},
                xticklabels={,,},
                yticklabels={,,},
                samples=100,
                xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                grid=both,
                major grid style={black!5},
                minor grid style={black!5},
                ]
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```